# React-redux is dispatching an API action when clearly, the request sent back 401 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to create a user authentication on my app. I created an api that will be called when ever a request is made on the app, so it can get the user's data using the id I passed in the request object.

The issue am having now is that when that api is called, since a user hasn't logged in, the token is null and the action (userLoaded) is not made to dispatch instead the getError and AuthError I caught in .catch should dispatch.

My redux console is showing that userLoaded was dispatched but getError and AuthError wasn't dispatched.

This is the code.....

```
The reducer
import {AUTH_ERROR, LOGIN_FAIL, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGOUT_SUCCESS, REGISTER_FAIL, REGISTER_SUCCESS, USER_LOADED, USER_LOADING} from '../action/types'

const initialState = {
  token : localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isAuthenticated : null,
  isLoading : false,
  user : null
}

export default function (state=initialState, action){

  switch (action.type) {

    case USER_LOADING:
      
      return {
        ... state,
        isLoading : true
      }

    case USER_LOADED:
      
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated :true,
        isLoading : false,
        user : action.payload
      }

    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
        isAuthenticated : true,
        isLoading : false
      }

    case AUTH_ERROR:
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case REGISTER_FAIL:
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      localStorage.removeItem('token') 
      
      return {
        ...state,
        token : null,
        isLoading : false,
        isAuthenticated : false,
        user : null
      }
  
    default:
      return state
  }



}

This is the action
import {AUTH_ERROR, LOGIN_FAIL, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGOUT_SUCCESS, REGISTER_FAIL, REGISTER_SUCCESS, USER_LOADED, USER_LOADING} from './types'

import {returnError} from './errorActions'


// So the first thing i have to do here is to check for a token and load it

export const userLoaded = () => (dispatch, getState) => {

  dispatch({type: USER_LOADING})

  // get the token from the current state

  const token = getState().auth.token

  // creating our header 

  const req = {
    headers : {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
  }

  // check if there's a token and if we have it, then we add it to the headers

  if(token){
    req.headers['x-auth-token'] = token
  }

  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/user', req)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => dispatch({
    type : USER_LOADED,
    payload : data
  }))
  .catch(err => {
    dispatch(returnError(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    dispatch({type: AUTH_ERROR})
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With fetch, errors will only be thrown if the connection is down or something similar. Fetch will still handle a 401 or 500 as a successful request - which is kind of right, because on a connection level nothing bad happened. So you'll have to check the result status code on your own and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer phry. Honestly,  I still can't understand how to handle that situation using fetch api, however, the code is working now because I switched to axios. I still don't understand why is working with axios. I really wish I can understand exactly what you meant but I know you're right so I will accept the answer but if you can explain to me better, I will appreciate it a lot.

Comment: `fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/user', req).then(res => { if (res.code > 299) { throw Error("error"); } return res; }).then(res => res.json())`

You literally just have to do that check yourself, in your own code.

Comment: Okay, now I understood what you meant! Thanks, for your time. I'm grateful